# pandas create column (assign value from other row)

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with 3 columns (id, parentId, version) and I need to add new column parentVersion (version from parentid) :

| id | parentid | version | parentVersion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1.1 | 2.1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.1 | 2.1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try creating a mapper out of the `id` and `version` columns with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) then calling [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on the `parentid` column:

```
df['parentVersion'] = df['parentid'].map(df.set_index('id')['version'])
```

`df`:

```
   id  parentid  version  parentVersion
0   1         2      1.1            2.1
1   2         2      2.1            2.1
```

---

The mapper:

```
df.set_index('id')['version']
```

Is a Series of values which associates ids with version:

```
id
1    1.1
2    2.1
Name: version, dtype: float64
```

Then map will match the value in the index of this series (from the `parentid` column) and replace it will the corresponding value.

---

Alternatively a self [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `id` and `parentid` then [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) out the unneeded columns:

```
df = df.merge(
    df, how='left',
    left_on='parentid', right_on='id', suffixes=('', '_y')
).rename(columns={'version_y': 'parentVersion'}).filter(regex='.*(?<!_y)$')
```

`df`:

```
   id  parentid  version  parentVersion
0   1         2      1.1            2.1
1   2         2      2.1            2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a dictionary containing the data : `data = {"id":[1,2], "parentid":[2,2], "version":[1.1,2.1], }`

Convert the dictionary into DataFrame:`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Declare a list that is to be converted into a column: `parentVersion= [2.1, 2.1]`

Using 'parentVersion' as the column name: `df['parentVersion'] = parentVersion`

Observe the result: `print(df)`